# Recoding variable into an ordered factor variable using 'car' in R

Tags: r

I am following the documentation from the `car` package in an effort to recode an ordered factor variable.

For example, in my data.frame `df`, I have a variable representing education (`BG_x`). I try recode it as:

```
df <- data.frame(
    BG_x = sample(1:8)
)
df$education<-recode(df$BG_x,"1:2='High school or less';3='Some college';4='College';5:8='Grad degree'", levels=c('High school or less','Some college','College','Grad degree'))
table(df$education)
```

However, when I check the distributions, the variables appear to be in alphabetical order instead of the order that I specified in the `recode` command. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer on using `recode`, but shows how you can do this with base R's `factor` + `levels`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(BG_x = sample(1:8))
df$education <- factor(df$BG_x, ordered = TRUE)
levels(df$education) <- list("High school or less" = 1:2, 
                             "Some college" = 3, "College" = 4, 
                             "Grad degree" = 5:8)
df
#   BG_x           education
# 1    3        Some college
# 2    8         Grad degree
# 3    4             College
# 4    5         Grad degree
# 5    1 High school or less
# 6    7         Grad degree
# 7    2 High school or less
# 8    6         Grad degree
table(df$education)
# 
# High school or less        Some college             College         Grad degree
#                   2                   1                   1                   4
```

---

Some time back, I wrote a convenience wrapper for those steps (assigning one level to multiple values) and [posted it as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7019545).

You can use it as follows:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist("7019545")
df$education <- Factor(df$BG_x, ordered = TRUE, 
                       levels = list("High school or less" = 1:2, 
                                     "Some college" = 3, "College" = 4, 
                                     "Grad degree" = 5:8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your original variable is not itself a factor, you need to include:

```
as.factor.result = TRUE
```

in your call to `recode`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using plyr's mapvalues function? I think it's a lot easier to implement than car's recode.

In your case it would be:

```
df$education <- as.factor(mapvalues(df$BG_x, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
c('High school or less','High school or less',"Some college","College","Grad degree",
"Grad degree","Grad degree","Grad degree")))
```

That looks simpler to my eyes for this example, though of course if you had one factor level that you wanted to replace a whole bunch of numbers with recode would be better.